# CoInitialize() on a separate thread crash without returning

Tags: c++, com

I follow the direct2d quickstart and all works well. but when I move the function from wWinMain to threadproc and start it in another thread, it crashes.

```
#include "GUI/gui.h"
#include "GUI/BaseWnd.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

DWORD WINAPI StartAnimation(LPVOID lpThreadParam)
{
    //HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
        printf("%d",hr);

        //if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)))
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            {
                BaseWnd map;

                //if (SUCCEEDED(map.Initialize(lpThreadParam)))
                if (SUCCEEDED(map.Initialize()))
                {
                    map.RunMessageLoop();
                }

            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        printf("{0}", e);
    }

    auto e = GetLastError();
    return -1;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    //initilize map
    //initialize(graph)

    //initialize window and base map according to model in anther THREAD

    //run solution provide 
    DWORD ThreadID;
    int a = 3;
    LPVOID lpThreadParam = &a;

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        StartAnimation,
        lpThreadParam, //input data
        0,
        &ThreadID
    );
    //StartAnimation(lpThreadParam);
    return 0;

}

int main() {
    return _tWinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), SW_SHOW);
}
```

In the above code, if I call `StartAnimation` directly in `wWinMain`, it works. but move it into thread, it crashes. 
when I debug, it never reaches code below CoInitialize(NULL), set the breakpoint to it, while on it, hit step over or step in or continue, the debug terminates. it never print anything. If I do not use thread, it will print 0.

Comment: If all that code is neccessary to reproduce your problem then chances are way higher that the problem is within your code than the call to `CoInitialize()` (btw. you should be using `CoInitializeEx()`). Also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: Threads aren't just about creating threads and starting them.  Maybe you want to do a [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) instead of the main program just terminating?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, exactly, such a noob question. The multithread mode of coinitialize() distract my attention. So I am looking into documents about that. I should have trusted time-tested code.

Comment: @Swordfish removed unrelated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "crash" you're seeing is unrelated to `CoInitialize`. The problem is that execution of the `wWinMain` function continues after the call to `CreateThread`. The next statement is `return 0;`, and program flow returns from `wWinMain`. At this point the process terminates and it's all over. Presumably you want some sort of loop that continuously handles something (input, logic, whatever) before you return from `wWinMain` instead of just ending the program.

Comment: exactly the problem. thanks. Now I understand why I cannot even reach breakpoints in threadproc when using continue. The thread had already terminated when main thread is returned?

Comment: @miehmg after `wWinMain()` exits, [`ExitProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) gets called: "*Ends the calling process **and all its threads**. Exiting a process causes the following: - **All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread, terminate their execution** without receiving a DLL_THREAD_DETACH notification...*"